# JVM crashes while web crawling with Apache Nutch 1.15 in Solaris 9

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch, sparc

JVM is crashing every time while web crawling using Apache Nutch 1.15 in solaris server.  Using 64 bit JVM 1.8.0_181-b13 for solaris-sparc.

Any idea to resolve below error.

JDK 1.8

Apache Nutch 1.15

This happens when crawl script is executed. Even tried downgrading to Apache 1.14.

**Please find the trace.**

```
Stack: [0xffffffff1b400000,0xffffffff1b500000],  sp=0xffffffff1b4fd640,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xd7d478]  Unsafe_GetLong+0x174
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J+-499088536
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J+0
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.FastByteComparisons$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo([BII[BII)I+74
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.FastByteComparisons$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo(Ljava/lang/Object;IILjava/lang/Object;II)I+16
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.FastByteComparisons.compareTo([BII[BII)I+11
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.compareBytes([BII[BII)I+8
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$Comparator.compare([BII[BII)I+39
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.lessThan(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z+70
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.PriorityQueue.upHeap()V+28
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.PriorityQueue.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;IILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+329
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;ILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+13
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/List;ILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;ZLorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+32
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/List;ILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+21
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.finalMerge(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+228
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.close()Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+101
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run()Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+390
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskUmbilicalProtocol;)V+312
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run()V+207
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x745b4c]  void JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*,methodHandle*,JavaCallArguments*,Thread*)+0x744
V  [libjvm.so+0x7442fc]  void JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*,KlassHandle,Symbol*,Symbol*,JavaCallArguments*,Thread*)+0x334
V  [libjvm.so+0x7445c0]  void JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*,Handle,KlassHandle,Symbol*,Symbol*,Thread*)+0x50
V  [libjvm.so+0x874704]  void thread_entry(JavaThread*,Thread*)+0xdc
V  [libjvm.so+0xd4433c]  void JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xf4
V  [libjvm.so+0xd44228]  void JavaThread::run()+0x320
V  [libjvm.so+0xb82298]  java_start+0x390
C  [libc.so.1+0xd8c48]  _lwp_start+0x8

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J+0
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.FastByteComparisons$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo([BII[BII)I+74
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.FastByteComparisons$LexicographicalComparerHolder$UnsafeComparer.compareTo(Ljava/lang/Object;IILjava/lang/Object;II)I+16
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.FastByteComparisons.compareTo([BII[BII)I+11
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.compareBytes([BII[BII)I+8
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.Text$Comparator.compare([BII[BII)I+39
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.lessThan(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z+70
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.PriorityQueue.upHeap()V+28
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.PriorityQueue.put(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+21
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;IILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+329
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger$MergeQueue.merge(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;ILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+13
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/List;ILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;ZLorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+32
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger.merge(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/List;ILorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/RawComparator;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/Counters$Counter;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progress;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+21
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.finalMerge(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+228
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.close()Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+101
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run()Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/RawKeyValueIterator;+390
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskUmbilicalProtocol;)V+312
j  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run()V+207
j  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Comment: Seems to be caused by a [bug in Hadoop when running on SPARC](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12720). It hardly can be fixed or worked-around in Nutch.